# Sending results from multiple mongo DB queries in one route to my view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get 2 sets of data from my database using simple mongo db queries. since im using 2 queries, how do I then pass both results to the view? I'm getting an internal server error currently. I want to be able to show the entire list of guardians and then show how many they are in a span.

Thank you very much

here is my code:

```
//show guardians
router.get('/guardians', middleware.isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    //ShOW ADMIN ALL guardians
    User.find({ isAdmin: false }, function (err, guardian) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('guardians', { guardian: guardian, currentUser: req.user });
        }
    });
    
    //Count all guardians
    User.countDocuments({isAdmin: false}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            var allGuardians = result;
            
            res.render('guardians', { allGuardians: allGuardians });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
router.get('/guardians', middleware.isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    //ShOW ADMIN ALL guardians

    let prom1 = User.find({ isAdmin: false })
    
    //Count all guardians
   let prom2 =  User.countDocuments({isAdmin: false});

   Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(result => {
      // do your things 
      //results will be array and you can get 
      //response of prom1 in result[0]
      //response of prom1 in result[1]
       //pass the data to view
   }).catch(err => {
//handle your error here
     console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
   })
            
});
```

Comment: thank you, manage to get the resulst from prom2, i cant get prom 1 though i  get the following error: Error : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object, how do i turn the object into a string?

Comment: JSON.stringify(send the object); it will convert it to string.

Comment: this is what i did But im still getting the same error.
`
var guardians = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
       var allGuardians = JSON.stringify(result[1]);
  console.log(allGuardians);
  console.log(guardians);
       res.render({currentUser: req.user, guardians:guardians, allGuardians:allGuardians });


`

Comment: I see what I did wrong I forgot to enter the view 'guardians'